# How to redirect with header use ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, redirect

I want to redirect from one controller to another through some custom headers.

SpringBoot 2.1.x

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("t1")
    ModelAndView t1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("token", "123");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/test/t2");
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("t2")
    String t2(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return request.getHeader("token");
    }
}
```

I wish the t2 controller returns the request header set by the t1 controller.

Comment: I've the same. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to answer a ModelAndView in Spring to redirect. You can asnwer a `Response` with status code of `302` for instance:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("t1")
    Response t1() {
        return Response.found("/test/t2") // just double check how you create this url as it might be invalid
        .header("token","123")
        .build();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("t2")
    String t2(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader("token");
    }
}
```

But the real question is: **What are you trying to achieve with this?**

It is never a good idea to make users jump from one controller to another just o pass a value between calls.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement the post-redirect-get-pattern:

there are three possibilities to handle redirect-attributes
1. adding flash/model-attributes to RedirectAttributes
2. adding request-parameter ('dynamic' attributes) to RedirectAttributes
3. adding request-parameter ('dynamic' attributes) to RedirectView

i combined the three possibilities in the following get-methods.

```
@PostMapping("/redirectme")
public RedirectView redirectme(final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    // the following attribute is a ModelAttribute
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageA", "A");
    final RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/redirectedpage", true);
    // the following attributes are request-parameter (dynamic Attributes)
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("messageB", "B");
    redirectView.getAttributesMap().put("messageC", "C");
    return redirectView;
}

@GetMapping("/redirectedpage")
public ModelAndView redirectedPage(
        // access FlashAttributes
        final Model model, @ModelAttribute("messageA") final String messageA,
        // access 'dynamic' Attributes
        @RequestParam("messageB") final String messageB, @RequestParam("messageC") final String messageC) {
    final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("red");
    modelAndView.addObject("caption", "App");
    // access FlashAttributes
    modelAndView.addObject("messageA_1", model.asMap().get("messageA"));
    modelAndView.addObject("messageA_2", messageA);
    // access 'dynamic' Attributes
    modelAndView.addObject("messageB", messageB);
    modelAndView.addObject("messageC", messageC);
    return modelAndView;
}
```